# How to replace a string in .txt files according to their name in php?

Tags: php, str-replace

I have a folder that contains several .txt files called :

A500_1.txt

A500_2.txt

A700_1.txt

A700_2.txt

A900_1.txt

...

In each of the .txt files there is :

PRXC1_|TB|CCAAO9-RC|9353970324463|24.99

PRXC1_|TB|CFEXK4-RC|9353970294766|84.99

PRXC1_|TB|CFEXK4-RC|9353970294773|84.99

...

I'd like you to :

- if the filename starts with A500_ replace "TB" with "MD"
- if the filename starts with A700_ replace "TB" by "JB"
- if the filename starts with A900_ replace "TB" with "LD"

How do you do it?

```
<?php

$oldMessage = 'TB';
$NewMessage = 'MD';

//read the entire string
$str=file_get_contents('./test/A500_1.txt');

//replace something in the file string
$str=str_replace($oldMessage, $NewMessage,$str);

//write the entire string
file_put_contents('./test/A500_1.txt', $str);
echo "good !";

?>
```

Comment: Do it like that what's the problem?

Comment: I can change a string in a file but not in all of them, that's the problem

Comment: It sounds like you need to find out how to read all the files from a folder, and how to loop through them and process each one in turn. You should be able to google both of those things quite easily. What research have you done? What code have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, make your file path a variable like `$path = './test/A500_1.txt';` then extract the filename with [basename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php). You will now have a variable to conditionally test against. Then consider that since you will be performing this action many times it should be a function that is easily reusable. This should look something like this:

```
function processFile( $path ) {
    $filename = basename( $path );

    //read the entire string
    $str = file_get_contents( $path );

    //replace something in the file string
    if ( strpos( $filename, 'A500_' ) === 0 ) {
        $str = str_replace( 'TB', 'MD', $str );
    } else if ( strpos( $filename, 'A700_' ) === 0 ) {
        $str = str_replace( 'TB', 'JB', $str );
    } else if ( strpos( $filename, 'A900_' ) === 0 ) {
        $str = str_replace( 'TB', 'LD', $str );
    } else {
        // Return false if we don't know what to do with this file
        return false;
    }

    //write the entire string
    $writeResult = file_put_contents( $path, $str );

    //return true after a file is written successfully, or false on failure
    return $writeResult >= 0;
}

if(processFile( './test/A500_1.txt' )) echo "good!";
```

From here it is likely a good idea to write a loop that iterates over all of the files you want to process. [scandir](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) is likely what you're looking for. Then re-use your new function inside this loop. Also, note that I added a check to make sure that the write is successful in the function. It's good practice to not always assume that a file is able to be written and explicitly check.

UPDATE: Example loop syntax since you asked.

```php
$files = scandir("./test/", 0);
foreach($files as $file)
{
    if(processFile( $file )) echo "$file is good!";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response! But at the end, I can't put the path of a folder for example "processFile( './test/' )" to scan it entirely?

Comment: @Patrick62 Yes, just use a loop with scandir as I mentioned in the paragraph below the code. I'll try to add an example to my comment if I get time.

Comment: I have this message : "Warning: file_get_contents(..): failed to open stream"

Comment: That typically means one of your file paths is incorrect or the program doesn't have read access to it. Check the paths and filesystem permissions.

Comment: No I figured, it's scandir trying to read "." so I added "if (!in_array($value,array(".",".."))) "